# Scroll to bottom of browser with silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a project in Silverlight which I'm adding controls at run time.
Every time I'm adding a control I want to scroll browser to the bottom of the page?
Any idea to how to scroll from Silverlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your Scrollbar is created by your application using the ScrollViewer you can do the following:

```
ScrollViewerName.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.PositiveInfinity);
```

if your scrollbar is created in the HTML page you'll have to invoke a script

#### Silverlight Script Invoke

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ScrollToBottom");
```

#### Java Script

```
window.onload=toBottom;

function ScrollToBottom()
{
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: i added alert(document.body.scrollHeight) it shows the new size but it dosent scroll to that position.i'm invoking the function right after adding a new dynamic control to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Does the function scroll at all?

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way to do it:
Use `textchange` event and in that execute `richtextbox.selectall();`